# Automate kendoUI upload control using codedUI test framework

Tags: upload, kendo-ui

When using codedUI as automation test framework to testapplication I am facing an issue with KendiUI upload control.

Issue: I record and playback the event of uploading a file from the UI developed using KendoUI upload control, but the automation framework doesn't show the progressbar indicating file uploaded, it shows the progressing icon for ever.

How do I get resolve of this

However it works fine when I manually try to upload the file, within secs its shows the progress bar and check mark appears indicating file has been uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced same issue but with help of Microsoft CodedUI support I was able to resolve this issue.

In the test method where you are trying to perform some functions like file upload etc using ajax related controls disable the `WebWaitForReadyLevel`. Please paste the below line of code in start of your test method

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebWaitForReadyLevel"] = "3";
```

which will actually disable it.

This disabling is at `testmethod` level so if you don't want to disable don't write any such code because by default `WebWaitForReadyLevel` is enabled.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is a bug in the codedUI framework and they are working on the resolution anyways. I appreciate Microsoft support team.

Comment: Also don't forget to add System.Configuration to your references